# How to get token for SOAP API call

Tags: python, soap

I need get data from Timewriter application using SOAP Api. I can make initial call in python with api key and user key with response 200.

```
import requests

url = "https://procloud.timewriter.nl/wsdl/timewriterapi.wsdl"

payload = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
            <S:Body>
            <ns2:Login xmlns:ns2="api.timewriter.nl">
                 <api_key>...key...</api_key>
                <user_key>...key...</user_key>
                <softwareDesc></softwareDesc>
            </ns2:Login>
            </S:Body>
            </S:Envelope>"""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
```

According to documentation https://timewriter.com/media/webhelpapi/ response should contain securityToken for use in other requests, but I cannot see any token in response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Header/> 
<S:Body>
  <ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="api.timewriter.nl">
    <result>
      <error></error> 
      <errorMessage/>
      <securityToken></securityToken>
    </result>
  </ns2:LoginResponse> 
</S:Body> 
</S:Envelope>
```

Any advice how to get security token from SOAP to use it for all other API requests?

Answer (score 0):

wrong url, correct one is url = "https://procloud.timewriter.nl/api/"